# When ever i run my code the while loop doesnt want to be nice and spits out an error that it can find a defined variable

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a hangman project for fun and when i have a while loop for my game it it says that secretword its not defined. but when i take it out it says that hangman is not defined, so i don't know why it isn't reading this or if my code isn't working in some way. When the code is running it all works until i choose the yes option then it comes up with and error, NameError: name 'secretWord' is not defined. If any one could help that would be AWESOME!!

```
import random


Head_man = ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|        ',
           '|        ',
           '|        ',
           '|        ']

Body_man = ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|       |',
           '|        ',
           '|        ',
           '|        ']

Body1_man= ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|       |',
           '|       |',
           '|        ',
           '|        ']

Body2_man= ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|       |',
           '|       |',
           '|       |',
           '|        ']


Right_man= ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|       |',
           '|       |\ ',
           '|       |',
           '|        ']


Left_man = ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|       |',
           '|      /|\ ',
           '|       |',
           '|        ']

Right_leg_man= ['________',
               '|       |',
               '|       O',
               '|       |',
               '|      /|\ ',
               '|       |',
               '|        \ ']

Full_man = ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|       |',
           '|      /|\ ',
           '|       |',
           '|      / \ ']


Full_Body= [(Head_man),
            (Body_man),
            (Body1_man),
            (Body2_man),
            (Right_man),
            (Left_man),
            (Right_leg_man),
            (Full_man)]







def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    '''
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters that represents what letters have not
      yet been guessed.
    '''
    import string
    fullstring = string.ascii_lowercase
    lettersLeft = ''
    for letter in fullstring:
        if letter not in lettersGuessed:
            lettersLeft = lettersLeft + letter
    return lettersLeft

def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters and underscores that represents
      what letters in secretWord have been guessed so far.
    '''
    wordGuessed = ''
    for letter in secretWord:
        if letter in lettersGuessed:
            wordGuessed = wordGuessed + letter
        else:
            wordGuessed = wordGuessed + '_ '
    return wordGuessed

def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secretWord are in lettersGuessed;
      False otherwise
    '''
    numCorrect = 0
    for letter in secretWord:
        if letter in lettersGuessed:
            numCorrect += 1
        else:
            return False
    return True

def HangMan(secretWord):
    guessesLeft = 8
    lettersGuessed =[]

    print('Welcome to the game Hangman!\n')
    print('I am thinking of a word that is ' + str(len(random.choice(secretWord))) + ' letters long.\n\n' )

    while guessesLeft > 0:
        if isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
            return print('Congratulations, you won!')
        print('You have ' + str(guessesLeft) + ' guesses left.')
        print('_________________________________Available Letters: ' + getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed))
        user_input = input('Please guess a letter: ')
        user_input = str(user_input)
        user_input = user_input.lower()

        if user_input not in lettersGuessed:
            lettersGuessed.append(user_input)
            print(scroll(Full_Body))

            if user_input in secretWord:
                print("Good guess: " + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
                print('-----------')
            else:
                print("Oops! That letter is not in my word: " + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
                print('-----------')
                guessesLeft -= 1
        else:
            print("Oops! You've already guessed that letter: " + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
            print('-----------')

    return print("Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was " + str(secretWord))

hangman =[('stackoverflow'),
          ('aaron'),
          ('bob'),
          ('storm'),
          ('fortnite'),
          ('yoda'),
          ('dog'),
          ('computer'),
          ('return'),
          ('hangman'),
          ('scarce'),
          ('smell'),
          ('sneeze'),
          ('needle'),
          ('stone'),
          ('dry'),
          ('cobweb'),
          ('blue'),
          ('green'),
          ('yellow'),
          ('purple'),
          ('black'),
          ('white'),
          ('python'),
          ('doctor'),
          ('brother'),
          ('pie'),
          ('explode'),
          ('laugh'),
          ('military'),
          ('chop'),
          ('shop'),
          ('secret'),
          ('input'),
          ('guess'),
          ('class'),
          ('teacher'),
          ('box'),
          ('dragon'),
          ('light'),
          ('buket'),
          ('pipe'),
          ('coffee'),
          ('mug'),
          ('faith'),
          ('cup'),
          ('blanket'),
          ('locker'),
          ('brick'),
          ('siren'),
          ('bottle'),
          ('water'),
          ('sticker'),
          ('time'),
          ('use')]





while input("Shall we play a game? [y|n] ") == 'y':
    HangMan(secretWord)

else:
    print("Ok, GoodBye")
```

Comment: you don't define secretWord in the global scope anywhere, you can fix it easily though with `HangMan(random.choice(hangman)[0])` instead of `HangMan(secretWord)`

Comment: but when i have hangman as my entire game it should work so when i call hangman it just runs the game.well it should. but i will take your advice

Comment: That's a lot of code. Python showed you the line with the error. Please post that entire traceback so we can find it too. This problem is usually easy to spot. If you look backwards from the line, is the variable assigned before use?

Comment: No i have the hangman variable assigned right below the definition of hangman, and is there any way to shorten the code  with the same result?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, here is what the fixed code looks like:

```
import random

#++++++++ 1
No_man =  ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|        ',
           '|        ',
           '|        ',
           '|        ',
           '|        ']
#========
Head_man = ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|        ',
           '|        ',
           '|        ',
           '|        ']

Body_man = ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|       |',
           '|        ',
           '|        ',
           '|        ']

Body1_man= ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|       |',
           '|       |',
           '|        ',
           '|        ']

Body2_man= ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|       |',
           '|       |',
           '|       |',
           '|        ']


Right_man= ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|       |',
           '|       |\ ',
           '|       |',
           '|        ']


Left_man = ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|       |',
           '|      /|\ ',
           '|       |',
           '|        ']

Right_leg_man= ['________',
               '|       |',
               '|       O',
               '|       |',
               '|      /|\ ',
               '|       |',
               '|        \ ']

Full_man = ['________',
           '|       |',
           '|       O',
           '|       |',
           '|      /|\ ',
           '|       |',
           '|      / \ ']


#________ 2
#Full_Body= [(Head_man),
#            (Body_man),
#            (Body1_man),
#            (Body2_man),
#            (Right_man),
#            (Left_man),
#            (Right_leg_man),
#            (Full_man)]
#--------
#++++++++
Full_Body= [No_man,
            Head_man,
            Body_man,
            Body1_man,
            Body2_man,
            Right_man,
            Left_man,
            Right_leg_man,
            Full_man]
#========







def getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed):
    '''
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters that represents what letters have not
      yet been guessed.
    '''
    import string
    fullstring = string.ascii_lowercase
    lettersLeft = ''
    for letter in fullstring:
        if letter not in lettersGuessed:
            lettersLeft = lettersLeft + letter
    return lettersLeft

def getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters and underscores that represents
      what letters in secretWord have been guessed so far.
    '''
    wordGuessed = ''
    for letter in secretWord:
        if letter in lettersGuessed:
            wordGuessed = wordGuessed + letter
        else:
            wordGuessed = wordGuessed + '_ '
    return wordGuessed

def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    '''
    secretWord: string, the word the user is guessing
    lettersGuessed: list, what letters have been guessed so far
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secretWord are in lettersGuessed;
      False otherwise
    '''
    numCorrect = 0
    for letter in secretWord:
        if letter in lettersGuessed:
            numCorrect += 1
        else:
            return False
    return True

def HangMan(secretWord):
    guessesLeft = 8
#++++++++
    bodyindex = 0
#========
    lettersGuessed =[]

    print('Welcome to the game Hangman!\n')
#________ 3
#    print('I am thinking of a word that is ' + str(len(random.choice(secretWord))) + ' letters long.\n\n' )
#--------
#++++++++
    print('I am thinking of a word that is ' + str(len(secretWord)) + ' letters long.\n\n' )
#========

    while guessesLeft > 0:
        if isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
#________ 4
#            return print('Congratulations, you won!')
#--------
#++++++++
            print('Congratulations, you won!')
            return
#========
        print('You have ' + str(guessesLeft) + ' guesses left.')
        print('_________________________________Available Letters: ' + getAvailableLetters(lettersGuessed))
        user_input = input('Please guess a letter: ')
        user_input = str(user_input)
        user_input = user_input.lower()

        if user_input not in lettersGuessed:
            lettersGuessed.append(user_input)
#________
#            print(scroll(Full_Body))
#--------
#++++++++ 5
            if user_input not in secretWord:
                bodyindex += 1
            print('\n'.join(Full_Body[bodyindex]))
#========

            if user_input in secretWord:
                print("Good guess: " + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
                print('-----------')
            else:
                print("Oops! That letter is not in my word: " + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
                print('-----------')
                guessesLeft -= 1
        else:
            print("Oops! You've already guessed that letter: " + getGuessedWord(secretWord, lettersGuessed))
            print('-----------')

#________
#    return print("Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was " + str(secretWord))
#--------
#++++++++
    print("Sorry, you ran out of guesses. The word was " + str(secretWord))
    return
#========

#________
#hangman =[('stackoverflow'),
#          ('aaron'),
#          ('bob'),
#          ('storm'),
#          ('fortnite'),
#          ('yoda'),
#          ('dog'),
#          ('computer'),
#          ('return'),
#          ('hangman'),
#          ('scarce'),
#          ('smell'),
#          ('sneeze'),
#          ('needle'),
#          ('stone'),
#          ('dry'),
#          ('cobweb'),
#          ('blue'),
#          ('green'),
#          ('yellow'),
#          ('purple'),
#          ('black'),
#          ('white'),
#          ('python'),
#          ('doctor'),
#          ('brother'),
#          ('pie'),
#          ('explode'),
#          ('laugh'),
#          ('military'),
#          ('chop'),
#          ('shop'),
#          ('secret'),
#          ('input'),
#          ('guess'),
#          ('class'),
#          ('teacher'),
#          ('box'),
#          ('dragon'),
#          ('light'),
#          ('buket'),
#          ('pipe'),
#          ('coffee'),
#          ('mug'),
#          ('faith'),
#          ('cup'),
#          ('blanket'),
#          ('locker'),
#          ('brick'),
#          ('siren'),
#          ('bottle'),
#          ('water'),
#          ('sticker'),
#          ('time'),
#          ('use')]
#--------
#++++++++
hangman =['stackoverflow',
          'aaron',
          'bob',
          'storm',
          'fortnite',
          'yoda',
          'dog',
          'computer',
          'return',
          'hangman',
          'scarce',
          'smell',
          'sneeze',
          'needle',
          'stone',
          'dry',
          'cobweb',
          'blue',
          'green',
          'yellow',
          'purple',
          'black',
          'white',
          'python',
          'doctor',
          'brother',
          'pie',
          'explode',
          'laugh',
          'military',
          'chop',
          'shop',
          'secret',
          'input',
          'guess',
          'class',
          'teacher',
          'box',
          'dragon',
          'light',
          'buket',
          'pipe',
          'coffee',
          'mug',
          'faith',
          'cup',
          'blanket',
          'locker',
          'brick',
          'siren',
          'bottle',
          'water',
          'sticker',
          'time',
          'use']
#========


while input("Shall we play a game? [y|n] ") == 'y':
#+++++++++ 6
    secretWord = random.choice(hangman)
#=========
    HangMan(secretWord)

else:
    print("Ok, GoodBye")
```

Footnotes:

1. For the purpose of your program it was a little more convenient to define a `No_man` variable that had a hangman with no body on it.
2. You don't need to put each list element in a tuple. Putting them in a list will suffice. Also while I didn't get any errors when each element was in a 1-element tuple, this might cause some problems if you do this for other functions which are sensitive to this so I would not recommend doing this.
3. You are choosing a random word here but you do not save it in a variable, which means it will be lost (and you actually didn't pass anything to the `secretWord` argument; see No. 6)
4. In Python, `print()` doesn't return anything. So if you type `return print('something')` that will raise a SyntaxError. You should use `print()` on one line and `return` by itself on the next line.
5. This is most likely where your while loop was spitting an error at. You're calling a function called `scroll()` but you did not define it anywhere. Actually, you don't need that function, because getting an element from the `Full_Body` array is easier to do.

   - I introduced another variable in your code called `body_index` for this. This is initially set to zero and every time a wrong guess is made, it is increased by one. For this to work the hangman parts all have to be in order which you have already done (and that's great).
   - To actually *draw* the hangman on the screen I took the hangman object you were about to print and I `join()`ed the strings inside with a newline. It works because the hangman object is actually a list of strings which should each be printed on one line.
6. Finally, the game was failing early complaining `NameError: name 'secretWord' is not defined`. The solution was to choose a random element from `hangman` and assign it to `secretWord`.